# How to limit work for mapping json to and from jpa objects

Tags: java, json, spring, jpa

in many tutorials I have seen that Classes which are representing rest `json` interface are using for `jpa` too, in my opinion it's not good practice (what if we want change `json`, but not `jpa`? we have to add ignore annotations etc). In production should I have 2 completely sets of Classes? In this case we have a lot of "plumbing code", how are you solving this problem?

Comment: For example we have enity Person which has id and Collection of Items, as JPA object we have a field Collection of object, but in rest interface we want to have only Collection of ids of Items

Answer (score 1):

I agree with you : you should have model for persistence (JPA) and model for services (JSON here).

> In this case we have a lot of "plumbing code", how are you solving
>   this problem?

The abstraction and the separation of responsibilities between logic layers have a cost.
If you want to have lighter objects in JSON for performance, security or better code maintainability, plumbing code is needed.
Writing clean and efficient code has a cost.

Before JSON, we had the same issue. 
 So as a rule of thumb, to avoid  plumbing code, we should try to keep the classes as many identical as possible and introduce only when it is relevant a variation between two objects representing the same thing but located in two different layers. In order of course to use mapping by reflection efficiently provided by third-party lib.

If you use jackson and [jackson-databind](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/), you have ready-to-use classes to do some custom mappings but of course if your mapping for a class is very specific, you should create at the hand the mapping for that class.
In your example with collection of Object in jpa vs collection of Id in json,
to avoid writing a lot of boiler plate and plumbing code, if this need is very common for you, you may develop an utility class to handle this need for any entity.